# Creating a CSS Table with a Numeric-Circle on the Border

Tags: css, geometry, border

I tried to create a simple Table with a Number through the Border - something similar to a pricing table.

I want to show some offers for our fight club in separate tables - image added.

Creating a custom Table and a round numeric-circle is not the problem, but positioning the Circle with the Number on the Border is too hard for me.

```css
.frametable {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #56b6f9 !important;
  padding: 1px;
}

.circlenumber::before {
    font-size: 2rem;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #1e73be;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    content: "1";
}
```

```html
<table class="frametable">
  <thead class="circlenumber">
  </thead>
  <tr>
  <td>A Box with some Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

I really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this kind of solution. I hope it works for you.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>sample</title>
      <style>
        .div {
          margin-top: 50px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 300px;
          border-color: blue;
          border:3px solid blue;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .div-circle {
          width: 60px;
          height: 60px;
          border: 3px solid blue;
          border-color: blue;
          border-radius: 60px;
          position: relative;
          background-color: blue;
          bottom: 30px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          color: white;
          font-size: 40px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="div">
        <div class="div-circle">
          <span>1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the number circles in the header of your table. Then move them up slightly by giving them a negative top margin.

```css
table {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #56b6f9 !important;
    margin: 2em;
}

th { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}

td { padding: 4em 1em; }

th span.circle {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: -22px auto auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><span class="circle">1</span></th>
        <th><span class="circle">2</span></th>
        <th><span class="circle">3</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: YESSS! That`s what i`m looking for :D
Thank you sooo much, really appreciate your help! Hope you have a good day.